# Strcpy in xcode

Tags: objective-c, c, c-preprocessor, strcpy

This is my code

```
char strings[10][10] = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
strcpy(strings[0], strings[0]);
```

I create a C project in Xcode, and then I run it which will be crash.
But if it is a Objective-C project, it will be no problem

Comment: What's your question? You are copying a string over itself, which is a strange thing to do. What are you hoping for?

Answer (score 2):

Calling strcpy when source and destination are overlapping (or identical as in your case) is undefined behaviour in C, C++, Objective-C and Objective-C++. Undefined behaviour means "anything can happen". "Anything" includes crashing with one compiler and not crashing with another compiler. It also includes worse things.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a C project, the strcpy will be replaced by 
`#if __has_builtin(__builtin___strcpy_chk) || defined(__GNUC__)`
`#undef strcpy`
`#define strcpy(dest, src)                  \`
`__builtin___strcpy_chk (dest, src, __darwin_obsz (dest))`
`#endif`